# Export All Relational Models to PDF from Oracle Data Modeler

Tags: oracle, erd, oracle-sql-data-modeler

Is there a way to export all Relational Models for a schema in Oracle Data Modeler to a single PDF file? Where each model is a separate page?

I have an ERD for my schema consisting of about 90 tables. This full model can be hard to read. To account for this, I have created several additional Relational Models that cover subsets of data. For example, another model that consists of just fives tables pulled from the full model, showing their mappings. This is to better demonstrate the relationships of this subset of data in our application's workflow. They relate to several other tables, but these five on their own more easily demonstrate how these items work together from a user's perspective.

I can print each relational diagram out to separate PDFs using File -> Print Diagram -> To PDF File..., but this leaves me having to manually combine nearly a dozen different PDFs. Is it possible to export them all out to a single file at once? Data Modeler seems to only focus on the open diagram that is in focus, and ignores everything else when I'm working with print options.

If that's not possible, is there at least a way to print all the models to separate files with a single click? Opening each model and printing them separately is overly time-consuming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not today.

What you can do, in version 4.2 is have your design/model with your smaller diagrams implemented as SubViews.

When you run the 'All Tables' report and export to HTML, you get a TOC/index page with links to the data dictionary reports for each object, and you also get links to each SubView diagram in the HTML. So it's a single report, with different pages for each diagram. It's just HTML instead of PDF.

It's NOT PDF, but I would argue slightly that HTML is easier to work with.

We could always create an ER to give you exactly what you're asking for though. I'm assuming that maybe Adobe Writer could take multiple PDF files and edit them into a single document as a workaround?

[image]

Comment: I wasn't using Adobe Writer, but that's basically what I was doing before. Editing all my PDFs into a single file.

But this sounds like a great solution. We aren't printing this to paper, given the size. They're only used digitally, so HTML is a fine alternative. More files to work with, but I can't imagine that having to open a zip will present any problems. Thanks!